# log4net logger hierarchy with similar log root names

Tags: .net, logging, log4net, hierarchy, appender

Have I found a bug here, or am I doing something wrong with this configuration?

```
<appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<logger name="MyApp.Common">
  <level value="WARN" />
  <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
</logger>
<logger name="MyApp.Common.Namespace.SomeGenericClass`1">
  <level value="INFO" />
  <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
</logger>
```

Presuming that I've named my loggers according to the standard "...DeclaringType" naming scheme, my expectation here is that everything under the MyApp.Common namespace will get logged to the console as long as it's a WARN or higher.  Anything in SomeGenericClass`1 will get logged if it's INFO or higher (and twice if it's WARN or higher due to the WARN logger).

What is happening is that anything in SomeGenericClass`1 that gets logged in INFO will be piped out to the console *twice*, instead of the expected once.  If I remove the more specific logger, nothing gets logged, and if I remove the less specific logger, things only log once, both as expected.  In addition, reversing the order of the loggers in the config file does nothing (as I would expect, since I would guess that order doesn't matter).

Did I find a bug here, or am I missing something important in how the hierarchy works?

Answer (score 2):

My experimental experience with using multiple logger nodes is that log4net will use the lowest level that you set in any particular logger. So even though you specified WARN in MyApp.Common, using INFO in MyApp.Common.SomeGenericClass caused the global(?) level setting to drop to WARN. So you got an entry from MyApp.Common as well as MyApp.Common.SomeGenericClass since the appender ConsoleAppender got fired twice.

What I was after was to get a subset of logs to go to a separate file. Not quite what you were stating in you question, but it does encompass what you want to do. And I did want to document my solution somewhere where I could find it again for my own benefit ;-).

I created two different loggers such as you have above, though one is root it will work the same. I then created two different appenders each filtering on different error levels and referred to them separately in the two loggers. What I get is the logs from OtherNamespace in one file and everything else in the other. The code for that is below.

```
<log4net>
<logger name="OtherNamespace">
  <appender-ref ref="OtherNamespaceAppender"/>
</logger>
<root>
  <level value="WARN"/>
  <appender-ref ref="MyRollingFileAppender"/>
</root>
<appender name="MyRollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="C:\Comanche\mylogfileFor_%property{User}.log" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <threshold value="ERROR" />
  <countDirection value="3" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />
  <maximumFileSize value="200KB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-6level%utcdate{ABSOLUTE} – %location :: %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="OtherNamespaceAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="C:\Comanche\OtherNamespace.log" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <threshold value="WARN" />
  <countDirection value="3" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />
  <maximumFileSize value="200KB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter">
    <acceptOnMatch value="true" />
    <LoggerToMatch value="OtherNamespace" />
    <!-- set your class name here -->
  </filter>

  <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />

  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-6level%utcdate{ABSOLUTE} :: %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Be aware that "everything else" was in another namespace so it did not get shunted into the OtherNamespace logger, which it could have if there would have been a name match of some sort. Also note that since everything inherits from root, if I had changed the logging level on the appender referenced by root to WARN, I would have gotten the OtherNamespace logs as well. All I wanted to achieve was to have more detailed logging go to a different file than everything else.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do what you want (did not test it):

```
<logger name="MyApp.Common">
     <level value="WARN" />
     <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
</logger>
<logger name="MyApp.Common.Namespace.SomeGenericClass`1">
     <level value="INFO" />  
</logger>
```

There is no need to reference the appender again, it is automatically inherited unless you set the [additivity](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger.Additivity.html) to false.