# Configure a log4net logger to match a generic class

Tags: c#, .net, generics, log4net

I want to configure one class in my application to log at the debug level, so I'm trying to set up a specific logger for that class. It's not changing to the debug level, though, and I suspect it's because the class is generic. I found [some examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5738485/4794) of configuration for generic types, so it looks like it's possible, but it's not working for me.

```
<root>
  <level value="INFO" />
  <appender-ref ref="OutputDebugStringAppender"/>
</root>
<logger name="MyCompany.MyGenericClass`1">
  <level value="DEBUG"/>
</logger>
```

Here's how I declare my logger in the generic class.

```
public abstract class MyGenericClass<T> : IDisposable where T : class
{
    private static ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyGenericClass<T>));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there are [two ways to get the class name](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#static-class-name), and one of them is a lot easier to configure in the logger.

If you change my logger declaration to this:

```
public abstract class MyGenericClass<T> : IDisposable where T : class
{
    private static ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(
        System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

Then my original configuration will work:

```
<root>
  <level value="INFO" />
  <appender-ref ref="OutputDebugStringAppender"/>
</root>
<logger name="MyCompany.MyGenericClass`1">
  <level value="DEBUG"/>
</logger>
```

It sounds like that `` `1 `` refers to the number of generic parameters the type has, but I'm not certain.

If you use my original logger declaration:

```
public abstract class MyGenericClass<T> : IDisposable where T : class
{
    private static ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyGenericClass<T>));
```

Then you need to use this ugly configuration:

```
<logger name="MyCompany.MyGenericClass`1[[MyCompany.MyParameterClass, MyLibrary, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=65af8642211d1afa]]">
  <level value="DEBUG"/>
</logger>
```

The second option also means that you need a separate configuration entry for each parameter type of the generic class.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a little late but I just faced the same problem...

Use

```
LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyGenericClass<T>).ToString())
```

This will work with a cfg looking like this:

```
<logger name="MyCompany.MyGenericClass`1[MyCompany.MyParameterClass]">
  <level value="DEBUG"/>
</logger>
```

Much shorter and no version number involved, which simplifies updating. Also note there's only one set of square brackets in the generic type definition instead of two with the solution that passes a `Type`.

Answer (score 0):

Coming from java (and thus knowing the log4xx paradigma very well), I do not see why the log outputs should print any generic class information at all. For the logger name of the generic base class it is not important to know which derivation exactly issues a log output.

Note that using the classname as logger name is only a convention. You can use an arbitrary other string as logger name. And - of course - also an arbitrary own logger hierarchy using the dot separater withing the logger name.

So I wrote a little LoggerName utility (to be honest, I was inspired by [this post](http://apache-logging.6191.n7.nabble.com/Problem-when-using-generic-classes-td24037.html)):

```
    public static string ClassNameForLogger(Type t)
    {
        if (t.IsGenericTypeDefinition || t.IsGenericType)
        {
            StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
            b.Append(t.Namespace).Append('.');

            int offset = t.Name.IndexOf('`');

            if (offset > 0)
            {
                b.Append(t.Name.Substring(0, offset));
            }
            else
            {
                b.Append(t.Name);
            }

            return b.ToString();
        }

        return t.FullName;
    }
```

And using it as this:

```
public abstract class MyGenericClass<T>
{
    private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(LoggerUtil.ClassNameForLogger(typeof(MyGenericClass<T>)));
```

Which delivers the logger name as

```
<MyNamespace>.MyGenericClass
```